# How to create a struct value from an id & value struct in javascript?

Tags: javascript, struct

I wonder if this is possible, but I want to give it a try.
I have an array like following:

```
srcStruct = {
    id: ["firstID", "secondID"],
    value: ["firstValue", "secondValue"]
};
```

I want to make a struct value from this array like this:

```
destStruct = {
    firstID: firstValue,
    secondID: secondValue
}
```

I tried like following, but not worked.

```
destStruct = {[srcStruct.id]: srcStruct.value};
```

Please tell me if this is possible, and how to do this.

Comment: Your input object is invalid. Objects must have key-value pairs, not just values.

Comment: Could you tell me more about that?

Comment: Hey @Harry, your first object is not a valid object. See [this](https://jsbin.com/kikayibuvu/edit?js,console)

Comment: Then, now is this possible?

Comment: @Harry you could do something like [this](https://jsbin.com/kikayibuvu/edit?js,console) but your "srcStruct" object needs to be a valid object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no nice syntax to create an object like you tried, you’d have to manually loop through object’s keys:

```
const destStruct = {};
srcStruct.id.forEach((id, i) => {
  destStruct[id] = srcStruct.value[i]
})
```

Or with Array’s reduce

```
const destStruct = srcStruct.id.reduce(
  (dest, id, i) => {
    dest[id] = srcStruct.value[i];
    return dest;
  }, {})
```

You can also check out lodash’s [zipObject](https://lodash.com/docs/#zipObject), which makes the code looks a bit nicer

```
import zipObject from ‘lodash/zipObject’;

const { id, value } = srcStruct; // destructuring
const destStruct = zipObject(id, value)
```

Hope it helps!